# DialogFragments and activities, passing info

Tags: android-activity, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to show a `DialogFragment` asking the user his name, and I need to get back this string to my main activity.

I've created an custom dialog fragment following the android guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

In my code, in response to the user click on positive button, I am able to call a function in my main activity:

```java
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.textdialog, null)).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   ((mainActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
               }
           }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   ((mainActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
}
```

where R.layout.textdialog is:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textdraw"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="introduce text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My question is, how could I get the text written by the user in my dialog fragment and send it back to my main activity?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I solved myself (but not sure if it's the better way)

I've done some changes in my `onCreateDialog`.

1. Save the view in a variable:

   `View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.textdialog, null);`
2. Save the edittext in a variable:

   `final EditText ed=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.textdraw);`
3. Send back the value in edittext variable when the user clicks the positive button:

   `getActivity()).doPositiveClick(ed.getText().toString());`

Full code is here:

```java
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.textdialog, null);
    // reference to the edittext
    final EditText ed= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.textdraw);


    builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   ((mainActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick(ed.getText().toString());
               }
           }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   ((mainActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
}
```

and the code in main activity:

```java
public void doPositiveClick(String ed){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hi, "+ed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```